# Convert an ActiveRecord relation to a specifically keyed Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ActiveRecord result set from the following query:

`people = People.where(job_type: ["Job Type 1", "Job Type 2"])`

This returns an AcitveRecord Relation.

I want to take `people` and convert it to a `Hash` where each key is the `job_type` and the value is an array of records that match that `job_type`.

The closest thing I found is `people.as_json` but that gives an array of hashes, not the format I'd like to work with.

What's an elegant Ruby way of converting the people data structure? Ideally it would look like:

`my_hash = {"Job Type 1" => [record1, record2..], "Job Type 2" => [..]}`

Comment: Can you please also add your desired output ?

Comment: I edited my post to include the desired hash output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to [group_by](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) `job_type`. So, give this a go:

```
people = People.where(job_type: ["Job Type 1", "Job Type 2"]).group_by(&:job_type)
```